# PHP Sorting of mutidimensional array based on more than one key values

Tags: php

I want to sort a multidimensional array based on 'distance' value.If distance are equal then i have to compare 'created' date then price and finally alphabetical order.Who can i sort an array based on different key values.

$array = array( 0 => array('title'=>'title1', 'distance'=>200, 'date'=>'2014-16','price'=>12),    1 => array('title'=>'title2', 'distances'=>100, 'date'=>'014-03-15','price'=>17));

array look like this.First priority to distnce then date and so on

Comment: check out [usort](http://www.php.net/usort) and write your own sorting function.

Comment: We need to see code to fix code. Post your array structure. What you have tried so far?

Comment: $array = array(
0 => array('title'=>'title1', 'distance'=>200, 'date'=>'2014-03-16','price'=>12),
1 => array('title'=>'title2', 'distances'=>100, 'date'=>'014-03-15','price'=>17),
); array look like this.First priority to distnce then date and so on

Comment: @user3398902 Add your additional context in the original question, not in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function for this exact thing,

Checkout My Gist:
https://gist.github.com/chazmead/8829079

```
<?php
/**
 * Sort a 2 dimension array with values in the second dimension
 *
 * Developer: chazmead89@gmail.com  // @RaggaMuffin-4201
 * 
 * Order can be string of a field, which will default to asc
 * OR as array(field1,field2...fieldn) each defaulting to asc
 * OR as assoc array(field1 => dir[asc|desc], field2 => dir[asc|desc]...fieldn
 * => dir[asc|desc])
 *
 * PHP Sort constants can be used: SORT_ASC | SORT_DESC
 *
 * @param array $array array to sort - passed by reference
 * @param mixed $order
 * @return null
 */
function multisort(&$array,$order) {

    usort($array, function($a,$b) use ($order) {
      $sortMap = array('asc'=>SORT_ASC,'desc'=>SORT_DESC);

      $aObj = (object)$a;
      $bObj = (object)$b;

      if (is_string($order))
        $order = array($order);

      if (is_object($order))
        $order = (array)$order;

      $i = 0;
      $cOrder = count($order);

      foreach($order as $field => $dir) {
        if (is_numeric($field)) {
          $field = $dir;
          $dir = SORT_ASC;
        }

        // Goto next step when a mis-match is found.
        if ($aObj->$field != $bObj->$field)
          break;

        // All fields match return 0
        if (++$i === $cOrder)
          return 0;
      }

      if(!is_numeric($dir)) {
        $dir = strtolower($dir);
        $dir = $sortMap[$dir];
      }

      $d = ($dir === SORT_DESC) ? -1 : 1;
      $c = ($aObj->$field < $bObj->$field) ? -1 : 1;

      return $c*$d;
    });
}
```

This can be used like so:

```
$array = array( 0 => array('title'=>'title1', 'distance'=>200, 'date'=>'2014-03-16','price'=>12), 1 => array('title'=>'title2', 'distances'=>100, 'date'=>'014-03-15','price'=>17), );

$order = array('distance' => SORT_ASC, 'created' => SORT_ASC, 'title' => SORT_ASC);

multisort($array,$order);
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept this as correct if it solved your problem ;)